# How to fix pygraphviz "Program dot not found in path" error in Azure or GCP

Tags: python

All of the posts on this topic so far involve a local machine and advise something similar to: "adding a directory containing the GraphViz binaries, like dot.exe, to the PATH environment variable, e.g., C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin". Unfortunately I'm not using a local machine and am unsure how to do the equivalent of this step on Azure using either the command line or within the Jupyter notebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 steps to deal with this:

1. Install GraphViz on an Azure or GCP virtual machine, you can use the package manager for your specific operating system.
   For ex, for Ubuntu OS:

   sudo apt-get install graphviz

For other OS, refer to this [link](https://graphviz.org/download/).

2. Add "dot" to the system's PATH: After installing Graphviz, you need to add the "dot" program to the system's PATH environment variable so that PyGraphviz can find it. You can add "dot" to the PATH by running the following command in the terminal:

   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/dot

This command adds the "/usr/bin/dot" directory to the PATH. If "dot" is installed in a different directory on your system, replace "/usr/bin/dot" with the correct path.

or you could also make use of Python:

import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/bin/dot'

Restart the program and see.